# Capistrano 2 - Permission denied - tmp/i18n-js.cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, i18n-gem

I frequently experience a problem with Capistrano deployment and i18n-js. 
Basically, I have a rails 3.2.16 application, which internalized for 2 languages (English and Japanese) using the i18n-js gem (version 2.1.2). When I deploy the app the process looks like the following (i need to run a couple of rake tasks):

```
bundle exec rake i18n:js:export
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I deploy on the staging server, this is the Capistrano file (capistrano gem version is 2.15.5) :

```
server "ec2-bla-bla.compute-1.amazonaws.com", :app, :web, :db

set :branch, "staging"
set :rails_env, "staging"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:i18n_js_export"

namespace :deploy do
  desc "I18n export"
  task :i18n_js_export do

  run "ps aux | grep unicorn | grep -v grep | awk '{system(\"kill -9 \"$2)}'; true"
  run "ps aux | grep sidekiq | grep -v grep | awk '{system(\"sudo kill -TERM \"$2)}'; true"
  run "export RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} && cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rake i18n:js:export"
  run "export RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} && cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rake db:migrate" 
end

task :unicorn_restart do
  run "sudo service unicorn_myapp restart; true"
  end
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Recreate symlink"
  task :resymlink, :roles => :app do
    run "rm -f #{current_path} && ln -s #{release_path} #{current_path}"
  end
end

after "deploy:assets:symlink", "deploy:resymlink"
after "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:unicorn_restart"
```

It is kinda funny, sometimes the script runs ok, but sometimes I get the following error:

```
* executing "export RAILS_ENV=staging && cd /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/current && bundle exec rake i18n:js:export"
    servers: ["staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com"]
    [staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] executing command
** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] 
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] Permission denied - /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/releases/20140407170608/tmp/i18n-js.cache
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js/engine.rb:52:in `initialize'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js/engine.rb:52:in `open'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js/engine.rb:52:in `write_hash!'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js/engine.rb:45:in `write_hash_if_changed'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js/engine.rb:33:in `block in <class:Engine>'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `_run__3095975217415606208__prepare__1788827297758520059__callbacks'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railti
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] es-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/releases/20140407170608/config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/releases/20140407170608/config/application.rb:87:in `invoke'
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] Tasks: TOP => i18n:js:export => environment
 ** [out :: staging.compute-a.aws.amazon.com] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 90439ms
```

It seems that the i18n-js.cache file is sometimes created as write protected.

Couple of things: 
    1. The i18n-js.cache is created not only in i18n:js:export, but in any following commands (db:migrate, assets:precompile)
    2. I tried to change the permission on it in between rake calls, but it does not work, because it seems that it is created inside the rake call, and access is denied during the same rake call:

```
    run "sudo chown ubuntu #{current_path}/tmp/i18n-js.cache"
```

Would really appreciate any help. Right now I have to manually see when it is appearing, so i can change the permissions by hand, which is kinda tedious

Comment: I'm also having this issue. I'd love to see if anyone has dealt with it successfully.